# How does Tiktok.com and Youtube shorts automatically play video on scroll (on mobile)? React Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

Using React JS, I'm trying to make a website similar to Tiktok, where on scroll, the video below it will play (with AUDIO, I know it's much easier without).

I tried to set this up with a `window.addEventListener("scroll",...)` set up. But on further research it seems like this doesn't work because the scroll isn't a "valid user input" to allow playing a video on mobile.

After more research it seems like playing then pausing all the videos from an initial user input click would work. Though I'm still working on how to play/pause all the videos from that single input.

Anyway, my question is how do websites like tiktok.com and youtube shorts autoplay videos with sound upon scrolling? How do they accomplish it?

Comment: try other valid user inputs. you can debug mobile in desktop chrome dev tools over usb if you want event listener details, inspection, breakpointing, etc.

Comment: Hi Dan, I know this works with "click" instead of scroll. I did the `window.addEventListener("click",...)` with the same code and it worked perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

I am sure there are many ways to do it.

One way I would do is to use `Intersection Observer API`

You can trigger some callback everytime you enter the view of the  of

as per docs some usecases

- Lazy-loading of images or other content as a page is scrolled.
- Implementing "infinite scrolling" web sites, where more and more content is loaded and rendered as you scroll, so that the user doesn't have to flip through pages.
- Reporting of visibility of advertisements in order to calculate ad revenues.
- Deciding whether or not to perform tasks or animation processes based on whether or not the user will see the result.

The Intersection Observer API allows you to configure a callback that is called when either of these circumstances occurs:

- A target element intersects either the device's viewport or a specified element. That specified element is called the root element or root for the purposes of the Intersection Observer API.
- The first time the observer is initially asked to watch a target element.

```js
let options = {
  root: document.querySelector('#scrollArea'),
  rootMargin: '0px',
  threshold: 1.0
}

let observer = new IntersectionObserver(callback, options);

// or

var intersectionObserver = new IntersectionObserver(function(entries) {
  // If intersectionRatio is 0, the target is out of view
  // and we do not need to do anything.
  if (entries[0].intersectionRatio <= 0) return;

  loadItems(10);
  console.log('Loaded new items');
});
// start observing
intersectionObserver.observe(document.querySelector('.scrollerFooter'));
```

I had made a small npm package for doing lazy loading.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/dyno-img-react

It basically shows a low res image till a user reaches the element ( I can configure the intersection area ). Once it reaches, I would fetch the high-quality image, and remove the observer

If its for RN, I have not really worked recently on RN, but you can check out this library

`react-native-intersection-observer`

It has an implementation which you can see in the code here.

https://github.com/zhbhun/react-native-intersection-observer/blob/master/src/IntersectionObserver.ts

It uses onLayout event to manage it internally

```js
import { IOScrollView, InView } from 'react-native-intersection-observer'

const Component = () => (
  <IOScrollView>
    <InView onChange={(inView: boolean) => console.log('Inview:', inView)}>
      <Text>Plain children are always rendered. Use onChange to monitor state.</Text>
    </InView>
  </IOScrollView>  
)

export default Component
```

Comment: Hey man! That's really nice you typed all this out. Though I have used a setup with Interaction Observer already. I actually got it to work that way on desktop, but unfortunately on mobile I still got the "NotAllowedError" where it doesn't let you play audio without a user interaction. So my issue is now getting it to work and registering as a user interaction to allow it. (Interaction Observer didn't count as interaction). Thanks regardless though man

Comment: You may need to change your question, because the question does not mention React Native anywhere, and it speaks about websites only.

There are libraries like react-native-intersection-observer that can help you implement in a similar manner.

`https://github.com/zhbhun/react-native-intersection-observer/blob/master/src/IntersectionObserver.ts

Comment: Yeah. It's not react native. It's React JS. It's a website/web app

Comment: can you provide more info on why it does not work on the mobile? I do understand that the itersection observer is still in working draft, which browser and what kind of an issue is happening?

Another way to solve it i feel is with virtualised lists, and I am guessing we can do something with onMount and manage. although I will have to look into exact implementation.

Answer (score 0):

Check [this guide](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Media/Autoplay_guide#autoplay_availability) for autoplay availibility:

- The audio is muted or its volume is set to 0
- The user has interacted with the site (by clicking, tapping, pressing keys, etc.)
- If the site has been whitelisted; this may happen either automatically if the browser determines that the user engages with media frequently, or manually through preferences or other user interface features
- If the autoplay feature policy is used to grant autoplay support to an  and its document.

Otherwise, the playback will likely be blocked. The exact situations that result in blocking, and the specifics of how sites become whitelisted vary from browser to browser, but the above are good guidelines to go by.

To allow [autoplay feature](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Feature-Policy/autoplay), you have to force your users by configuring options to allow. Here's a feature policy that you can try with in header:

```
Feature-Policy: autoplay
```

Allowing autoplay in iframe:

```
<iframe src="mediaplayer.html"
  allow="autoplay 'src'">
</iframe>
```

But browsers block autoplay with audio as their policy - user can feel irritation with the sound that is automatically appear. So, all thing you have to set a configuration for them to allow to play with sound.

For full information about autoplay, follow the [guide](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Media/Autoplay_guide). You can also check [this tool](https://chromeenterprise.google/policies/?policy=AutoplayAllowed) to see what devices are allowed for autoplay along with [autoplay policy](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/09/autoplay-policy-changes).

Comment: Are you saying that iframe could be used to autoplay video with sound? Or no?

Comment: Iframe can be used, but currently the browser policy has been changed and do not allow to autoplay. You have to enforce user to enable feature autoplay. You may get full help you carefully read the docs.

Comment: Yeah, I'm trying to figure out how tiktok.com (on mobile) auto-plays on scroll.